# Python multiprocessing - "outer product" of arguments

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, parameter-passing, python-multiprocessing

I'm doing a numerical simulation with multiple input parameters. Some of these parameters are static, while some are arrays of numbers I want to run my function at. For example, I may want to simulate the following set of parameters

```
a = 1
b = np.arange(1, 11)
c = np.arange(20, 31)
d = 1
```

Which would mean running

```
simulate(a = 1, b = 1, c = 20, d = 1)
simulate(a = 1, b = 1, c = 21, d = 1)
...
simulate(a = 1, b = 1, c = 30, d = 1)
simulate(a = 1, b = 2, c = 20, d = 1)
...
```

i.e. 100 calls to `simulate()`. I want to use multithreading to speed this up. I tried using multiprocessing's `pool.map()`, but the requirement for the structure of the input parameters requires instantiating a length-100 array containing lists of a, b, c, and d, e.g. `[[1, 1, 20, 1], [1, 1, 21, 1] ...`

In actuality I have enough parameters and am varying in enough dimensions that I run out of memory trying to generate the input array for pool.map().

What I'd like is to have a function `map_wrapper()` such that

```
a = 1
b = np.arange(1, 11)
c = np.arange(20, 31)
d = 1
map_wrapper(simulation, [a, b, c, d])
```

Is equivalent to the 100 calls of `simulation()` listed above, or a way of using `map()` or similar in the same way.

Comment: Side note - while researching solutions to this I came across multiprocessing's asynchronous functions. Am I correct that asynchronous would be faster but may cause headaches trying to organize the results of the simulation?

Comment: how does `simulate` return results. That makes a difference in how you organize results. asynchronous pool calls aren't inherently faster, they just let the main thread do other things at the same time until results are ready. `pool.apply` only enques a single task, and will block until it's done, while `apply_async` allows more tasks to be enqueued. `pool.map` blocks, but it enqueues multiple tasks, so more things can get to work at the same time.

Comment: as for answering your first question, you can pass a generator to `pool.map` which generates the inputs on the fly so memory consumption is limited.

Comment: `simulate` just returns a float.

Can you please expand on passing in a generator?

Comment: `pool.starmap(simulate, ((1, b, c, 1) for c in np.arange(20,31) for b in np.arange(1,11)))` - off the cuff, may need debugging... but map should consume from the iterator rather than building the entire array all at once

Comment: Ok, that's very helpful. I can do something like `(1, bgen, cgen, 1) for cgen in c for bgen in b` but will need to make it so that it's `(agen, bgen, cgen, dgen)` without errors since I don't know ahead of time which parameters will be scalars or arrays. I'll continue tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal example showing how to build a generator that yields args for a multiprocessing function:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def gen_args():
    for a in range(4):
        for b in range(4,8):
            for c in range(8,12):
                yield (a,b,c)
                
def foo(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as p:
        res = p.starmap(foo, gen_args())
```

This will generate 64 tasks, but the arguments are calculated on the fly as needed rather than all at once at the beginning. Keep in mind you'll still need the space for the output list. Using the `chunksize` argument for starmap may or may not improve execution speed (test it both ways to find out), but it will increase memory usage somewhat, as it pulls multiple sets of args at a time for each worker function to work on.

Comment: This works well. It's simple enough to make the generator take as an argument my parameters `gen_args(params)` and convert the scalars to length-1 lists. If I want to make the generator work without needing rewriting if I add or remove parameters in the future, do you see a better way to do that than making the function recursive?

Comment: If you want to combine more iterators you really could just use `itertools.product`... It does basically that